# error running exitwp to convert a xml file in a collection of posts for jekyll

Tags: python, jekyll

I am trying to migrate from Squarespacet to jekyll by running [exitwp](https://github.com/thomasf/exitwp) on a xml file I exported from Squarespace.

I received this error:

```
writing.Traceback (most recent call last):
File "exitwp.py", line 371, in <module>
  write_jekyll(data, target_format)
File "exitwp.py", line 293, in write_jekyll
  i['date'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').replace(tzinfo=UTC()),
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
  (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'No Content Found' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: improve code formatting

Comment: @sigul try using another plugin, like this one: https://gist.github.com/evanwalsh/6131008 I believe that's for moving from wordpress to jekyll, hence exitwp.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, found it when googling the same error message.

In my exported xml file from Squarespace I had a lot of pages     (`<wp:post_type>page</wp:post_type>`) that were missing the `post_date` tags.

I just added them after the `pubDate` tag <s>, it worked without the actual date:</s>

```
<pubDate>Sat, 05 May 2012 12:53:33 +0000</pubDate>
<wp:post_date>2012-05-05 12:53:33</wp:post_date>
<wp:post_date_gmt>2012-05-05 12:53:33</wp:post_date_gmt>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just submitted a fix for that error:
https://github.com/thomasf/exitwp/pull/77